Remember image URLs in a Jetpack Compose function to prevent reloading on screen rotation?
I'm working on a Jetpack Compose function called ImageWithCustomStates, which loads images from a URL. However, I encounter an issue where the image URL does not persist when the screen rotates, causing the image to reload unnecessarily.
Note: Container object has Image URL

@Composable
fun ImageWithCustomStates(
    isLoading: Boolean,
    container: Container,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    newImage: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.service_upload_images),
    error: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.image_loading_failed),
) {
    // Remember the image URL
    val imageUrl = remember(container.image?.imageUrl) { container.image?.imageUrl }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Create image request
    val imageRequest = remember(imageUrl) {
        ImageRequest.Builder(context)
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
            .data(imageUrl)
            .crossfade(true)
            .build()
    }

    // Load the image
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = imageRequest)

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading")
        }

        // Additional UI states (error, success, etc.) can be handled here
    }
}




Why not cache the image and if url is same, use cached image instead of re-requesting? View will always be regenerated after screen rotates.

Welcome @Santhosh Kumar! If an answer resolved your issue, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of the answer.

No it is not one that i expected!

Use rememberSaveable instance of remember
rememberSaveable creates a State object that persists its value across configuration changes. When the composable is recomposed due to a configuration change, the saved value is restored.
val imageUrl = rememberSaveable(container.image?.imageUrl) { container.image?.imageUrl }


The problem is image is reloaded again when failure occurred/error, in this case i needed to avoid loading state again when screen is rotated. so i changed the code to this,
@Composable
fun ThumbnailImage(
    imageUrl: String?,
    placeholder: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.placeholder),
    error: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.error)
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        if (imageUrl != null) {
            var hasError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

            val imageRequest = remember(imageUrl) {

                ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                    .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
                    .data(imageUrl) // Use savedUrl.value here
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.service_upload_images)
                    .error(R.drawable.image_loading_failed) // Set error image directly
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .build()
            }

            if(hasError){
                Image(
                    painter = error,
                    contentDescription = "No image available",
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(12.dp)
                        .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)))
            }else{
                // Image loading with effect
                SubcomposeAsyncImage(
                    model = imageRequest,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    contentDescription = "Image",
                    loading = {
                        ShimmerBox(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            shimmerBackgroundContainerColor = Color.LightGray
                        )
                    },
                    onSuccess = {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image loaded successfully")
                    },
                    onError = {
                        hasError=true
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading image")
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(12.dp)
                        .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                )
            }

        } else {
            Image(
                painter = placeholder,
                contentDescription = "No image available",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(12.dp)
                    .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            )
        }
    }
}


